# How can I make images move under each other, when using a responvie theme?

Tags: html, css

I have 8 pictures i a row, and when I resize my screen, I would like those images to swap place, so when I go down to mobile phone view, the 8 images are not in a row anymore, but in a column.

Question:
Can anyone advise me how that is best done? Please see attachment. 
I am using a table build with divs and styled with CSS.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="tablecategory">
<div class="tr_cat">
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="td_cat"><img src="images/small_sample_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="tr_cat">
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
<div class="td_cat"><a href="#">Kategorinavn</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
         div.tablecategory {
        display: table; 

        }
    div.tr_cat {
        display: table-row; 
        width:10%;

        }
    div.td_cat {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        border: 1px solid white;
        }

    div.td_cat a{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:block;
        background:#cce;
    }
    div.td_cat a:hover{
     background:#ecc;
    }

    div.td_cat img {
        border: 1px solid white;
        width: 100%;
            }
```

See example image here: http://elkaer2.nioba.dk/example.png

Comment: Float the images instead of using a table. They will automatically be placed below eachother if the screen is not wide enough (don't even need to use any responsive-nes).

Answer (score 0):

```
div.td_cat {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

in this css you just add bellow code and remove display: table-cell;

```
   display:block;
   float:left;
```

Comment: Can you explain him instead of simply posting the code here? As it will help him to get his issue solved

Comment: Hmm, it seems to break the line, so I now have two rows of pictures, when using full screen size.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

http://jsfiddle.net/fdjsf/2/

```
div.tablecategory {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
      background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
div.tr_cat {
    display: table-row;
    width: 10%;
}
div.td_cat {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid white;
    float:left;
}
div.td_cat a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #cce;

}
div.td_cat a:hover {
    background: #ecc;
}
div.td_cat img {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7FRb/) link.
I have just added float: left, and display :block in following css.

```
div.td_cat {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        border: 1px solid white;
        display:block;
       float:left;
        }
```